# How to rotate and prevent unwanted coloring of black and white image imported into R

Tags: r, image, image-processing, png, ppm

Background: I'm trying to follow the steps on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179042/67822)

I have downloaded the image, and made it accessible [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwl-HpVJ_5Peek1Pc2R1S3g4N1k/view?usp=sharing). It is saved in the R directory as `baboon.png`:

[image]

Now from R studio I have

```
library('png') # used the png package
image = readPNG('baboon.png') # to read the image
```

From there the steps in the rest of the post can be followed. For instance,

```
baboon.svd = svd(image) 

baboon.1   =  sweep(baboon.svd$u[,1,drop=FALSE],2,baboon.svd$d[1],"*") %*%
  t(baboon.svd$v[,1,drop=FALSE])
baboon.20  =  sweep(baboon.svd$u[,1:20,drop=FALSE],2,baboon.svd$d[1:20],"*") %*%
  t(baboon.svd$v[,1:20,drop=FALSE])
baboon.250 =  sweep(baboon.svd$u[,1:250,drop=FALSE],2,baboon.svd$d[1:250],"*") %*%
  t(baboon.svd$v[,1:250,drop=FALSE])
image(baboon.1)
image(baboon.20)
image(baboon.250)
```

However,

1. The images produced are rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise.
2. They include color information, which wasn't there in the original png.

Here is an example:

[image]

I believe that I may need to convert the png image into a ppm file to be able to discard color (?), but in general I'd like to ask for help regarding the two problems mentioned: rotation and unwanted color.

Answer (score 1):

How about you try this.

```
install.packages("raster")
install.packages("rgdal")
library(raster)
r1 <- brick("baboon.png")#please use any jpg image
plotRGB(r1)
png("baboonNew.png",width=nrow(r1),height=ncol(r1))
plotRGB(t(flip(r1, 1))) 
dev.off()
```

I guess I had not really understood what you were looking for. I see you got an answer, try this one too:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
img <- "baboon.png"
photo.raster<- raster(img)
photo.flip <- flip(photo.raster, 2)
photo.raster <- t(as.matrix(photo.flip))
dim(photo.raster)

image(photo.raster, col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

Comment: `r1 <- brick('baboon.png')#please use any jpg image
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, objecttype = "RasterBrick", ...) : 
  Cannot create RasterLayer object from this file; perhaps you need to install rgdal first`

Comment: +1 I appreciate your help. But ultimately your code seems designed to save a png image. Yet, what I need is a matrix to feed into `svd`.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is the answer I was looking for:

First off, we need to download the package `EBImage`, which is not immediately available in R versions 3.3.1 or more recent. We can do that by going to [Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___Software), where the package is available with [clear code lines](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html) to copy and paste into R for installation:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
```

The rest just follows:

```
library(png)
library(EBImage)

img = readImage("baboon.png")
display(img, method="raster")
dim(img)
is.matrix(img)
baboon.svd = svd(img) 

baboon.1   =  sweep(baboon.svd$u[,1,drop=FALSE],2,baboon.svd$d[1],"*") %*%
  t(baboon.svd$v[,1,drop=FALSE])


display(baboon.1, method="raster") #89 KB saved as png 646 x 466

baboon.20  =  sweep(baboon.svd$u[,1:20,drop=FALSE],2,baboon.svd$d[1:20],"*") %*%
  t(baboon.svd$v[,1:20,drop=FALSE])

display(baboon.20, method="raster") #179 KB saved as png 646 x 466

baboon.250 =  sweep(baboon.svd$u[,1:250,drop=FALSE],2,baboon.svd$d[1:250],"*") %*%
  t(baboon.svd$v[,1:250,drop=FALSE])
display(baboon.250, method ="raster")
```